# how to align subscribe button next to email field?

Tags: html, css, forms

on this page: http://growthbay.ch/

I have a small email field plus subscribe button embedded, but I would like to show the subscribe button right next to the email input field with a bit of a margin to the left of the subscribe button.

I am using this code:

```html
<label><strong>Get the latest jobs in your inbox!</strong></label>
<input style="width:auto !important" type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="your@email.com" required />
<input display="inline-block" position="relative" margin-left="5px" vertical-align="top" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

thanks folks!
Sandro

Comment: There are many ways to align things side-by-side - most regularly in sites built nowadays is probably flexbox, grid or bootstrap. Please add the actual CSS from your website to your snippet so we can get a better idea of what's going on with your site (external links are never permanent).

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: inline-block;` instead of `display:block` from your css

Comment: Thank you Besart! unfortunately, this didn't do anything :-/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you missed `display: inline-block` on the email field. Just add it, and it should work!

Also (albeit not related to your problem), you did not apply styles to the "Subscribe" button in the correct way: what you have is

```html
<input display="inline-block" position="relative" margin-left="5px" vertical-align="top" type="submit" value="Subscribe"/>
```

while it should be:

```html
<input style="display: inline-block; position: relative; margin-left: 5px; vertical-align: top;" type="submit" value="Subscribe"/>
```

In general, however, I recommend using external CSS and referencing your element with classes.

Let me know if it worked!

Comment: hello Damiano, thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately this didn't help. The second tip is implemented though ;-)
Any other ideas?

Comment: @SandroMeyer Hmm, from what I can see the code hasn't changed at all. Unfortunately, I'm not really a WordPress guru, so I won't be able to help you a lot there.